# psql and pg_dump version mismatch

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

```
omnia@ubuntu:~$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.4
omnia@ubuntu:~$ pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 9.2.8
omnia@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -l | grep pg
ii  gnupg                            1.4.11-3ubuntu2.5                 GNU privacy guard - a free PGP replacement
ii  gpgv                             1.4.11-3ubuntu2.5                 GNU privacy guard - signature verification tool
ii  libgpg-error0                    1.10-2ubuntu1                     library for common error values and messages in GnuPG components
ii  libpq5                           9.3.4-1.pgdg60+1                  PostgreSQL C client library
ii  pgdg-keyring                     2013.2                            keyring for apt.postgresql.org
ii  postgresql-9.2                   9.2.8-1.pgdg60+1                  object-relational SQL database, version 9.2 server
ii  postgresql-9.3                   9.3.4-1.pgdg60+1                  object-relational SQL database, version 9.3 server
ii  postgresql-client-9.2            9.2.8-1.pgdg60+1                  front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.2
ii  postgresql-client-9.3            9.3.4-1.pgdg60+1                  front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.3
ii  postgresql-client-common         154.pgdg60+1                      manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common                154.pgdg60+1                      PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
ii  python-gnupginterface            0.3.2-9.1ubuntu3                  Python interface to GnuPG (GPG)
ii  unattended-upgrades              0.76ubuntu1                       automatic installation of security upgrades
ii  update-manager-core              1:0.156.14.13                     manage release upgrades
omnia@ubuntu:~$
```

Seems I have both installed but pg_dump is stuck in an older version? Weird since both are linked to the same "wrapper":

```
omnia@ubuntu:~$ readlink /usr/bin/psql
../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper
omnia@ubuntu:~$ readlink /usr/bin/pg_dump
../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17):

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/pg_dump
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dump
```

Comment: Can do just `sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dump`

Comment: this is deleted my backup option

Comment: While this answer will work, it's a bit crude and leaves the problem for pg_dumpall, pg_isready, etc etc.

Answer (score 7):

If your *pg_dump* is sym-linked to *pg_wrapper*, then the best fix is to tell *pg_wrapper* which version to use.

Append

```
*   *   9.6     localhost:5432     *
```

to `/etc/postgresql-common/user_clusters`, (assuming your postmaster is listening on localhost:5432 of course).

This then fixes the problem for all *pg_* commands, doesn't involve breaking anything, and scales nicely for future versions which you may wish to install.

See `man pg_wrapper` and `man postgresqlrc` for details and other options.

NB This answer is specifically for Debian/Ubuntu, and is most likely applicable when there are two version of pg installed, eg. after an upgrade.

Comment: Works perfectly and is much nicer than messing with links.

Comment: What if I don't even have a local server? I just have postgresql-client installed

Answer (score 0):

The `pgdg60` package suffix leads me to believe these packages are not from the official Ubuntu repository. Try  looking into `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and see if you have any third party PPA's or repositories specified.

Try getting the Postgresql packages either from your Ubuntu repo (although these may be a bit out-of-date depending on your Ubuntu version), or from the official postgres repo (they provide an apt server for Ubuntu/Debian): https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

Comment: Unfortunately ubuntu's official packages are outdated

Comment: @PabloFernandez Depends on what version of Ubuntu you are using. 14.04 has the latest. Eitherway, I would try the following: `apt-get remove postgresql-9.2` and `apt-get install postgresql-9.3` - you won't lose your database data unless you replace `remove` with `purge`